# How do I properly build and nest structs to unmarshal a SOAP response in Go?

Tags: xml, go, soap, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble unmarshalling a SOAP response with `encoding/xml` in Go. (Code and excerpts below.)

1. Are the values I'm using to initialize the struct fields wrong? (Eg, `xml:"xmlns:soap,attr"`)

Most of the examples in the blog posts I've been learning from don't use XML fields with prefixes, like `<soap:Body>`. So I don't fully understand how to parse those with this package.

2. Are my structs nested improperly?
3. Do I need to provide structs and fields for **every element and attribute** in order for `xml.Unmarshal` to correctly populate the structs?

Eg, if I don't provide a struct field for `<soap:Envelope>` or `<soap:Body>`, will `xml.Unmarshal` ignore the contents of those elements? Or can I provide structs and fields only for the elements I want to unmarshal (eg, only the elements represented in the `ResData` struct)?

I may be missing some obvious things here, because I'm very new to both Go and SOAP. I don't fully understand how `encoding/xml` works, even after reading through a few blog posts showing examples of how to use it, and reading through some of the Go documentation. I may just be dense.

Here's the full test code in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VlPUsQB8jrY). I get nothing when I run it:

```
[~/d/xml]% ./xmltest
Url:
Name:
Protocol:
Version:
Id:
```

This is the SOAP response I'm trying to unmarshal:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <GetCompanyWsdkUrlResponse xmlns="http://corrigo.com/integration/">
         <GetCompanyWsdkUrlResult xsi:type="GetCompanyWsdkUrlResult">
            <Url>https://am-ce96e.corrigo.com/wsdk/CorrigoService.asmx?wsdl</Url>
            <CompanyName>ACME Test Company</CompanyName>
            <Protocol>HTTPS</Protocol>
            <CompanyVersion>9.6</CompanyVersion>
            <CompanyId>1337</CompanyId>
         </GetCompanyWsdkUrlResult>
      </GetCompanyWsdkUrlResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

These are the structs I'm unmarshalling the data into:

```
type Envelope struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name    `xml:"Envelope"`
    XMLNSs      string      `xml:"xmlns:soap,attr"`
    XMLNSxsi    string      `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
    XMLNSxsd    string      `xml:"xmlns:xsd,attr"`
    Body
}

type Body struct {
    Body        string      `xml:"Body"`
    Response
}

type Response struct {
    UrlResponse string      `xml:"GetCompanyWsdkUrlResponse"`
    XMLNSs      string      `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    Result
}

type Result struct {
    UrlResult   string      `xml:"GetCompanyWsdkUrlResult"`
    XMLNSxsi    string      `xml:"xsi:type,attr"`
    ResData
}

type ResData struct {
    Url         string      `xml:"Url"`
    Name        string      `xml:"CompanyName"`
    Protocol    string      `xml:"Protocol"`
    Version     string      `xml:"CompanyVersion"`
    Id          string      `xml:"CompanyId"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In the order of your numbered questions)

1.
Ahhh, you were so close! The biggest thing is that you were leading the "xsi:" and "xmlns:" which you don't need to. I do believe that Go ignores those values and just looks at the fields afterwards.

Taking your Envelope struct it *should* be this (your other structs need to be adjusted as well where appropriate):

```
type Envelope struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    XMLNSs   string   `xml:"soap,attr"` // Note the lack of `xmlns:`
    XMLNSxsi string   `xml:"xsi,attr"`
    XMLNSxsd string   `xml:"xsd,attr"`
    Body     Body     `xml:"Body"` // Note how we tell go about the body tag here
}
```

2. 

Slightly touched on this already with the `body` in the code block above. But yes, there's many different ways of doing it, but I'll post a link to go playground where you'll find a worked example of a series of structs that parse the SOAP XML you provided correctly.

https://play.golang.org/p/L2F4bduac-3

3.
Nope, you can choose to define only what you need form the SOAP. Let's pretend you ONLY needed Company ID. You could just make your struct:

```
type OnlyCompanyID struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    CompanyID int      `xml:"Body>GetCompanyWsdkUrlResponse>GetCompanyWsdkUrlResult>CompanyId"`
}
```

EDIT: I'd highly recommend taking what I put into go playground and messing around with it. Unmarshling XML, in my opinion, is a little trickier than something more straight forward like JSON/YML in Go. Feel free to drop any follow up questions and I can see what I can do to address them :)

Comment: Oh it's fantastic that I can select only what I want to unmarshal (RE #3). It seems to work a little like XPath. I initially wanted to just use XPath, but the Go implementations of it don't seem too great. RE #1,2: Seems like `encoding/xml` automatically recognizes prefixes, so I can omit. SUPER helpful response, it'll help while I'm messing around with these things. thank you! :>

Comment: Another question actually: If I want to select only the fields I want with the `>` syntax, do I need to provide an `XMLName` field only for the **very first XML element**?

Comment: "Another question Actually":

I don't know to be honest, but it seems to break when I don't put XMLName, nor can I find anything useful of note at my goto source: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal.

But what I _can_ say is that it doesn't seem to work without XMLName. (I don't use XML at all in my day job with Go so sadly I've limited experience with it, apologies).